# VNDocumentCameraScan to searchable PDF

Tags: ios, swift, ios-pdfkit, visionkit

I am currently trying to create a searchable `PDFDocument` after I have obtained a `VNDocumentCameraScan` with the help of the `VNDocumentCameraViewController`.

Currently I only take the images of the scan and put them into a `PDFDocument` instance.

```swift
func documentCameraViewController(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController, didFinishWith scan: VNDocumentCameraScan) {
   let pdf = createPDF(from: scan)
} 

fileprivate func createPDF(from scan: VNDocumentCameraScan) -> PDFDocument {
    let pdfDocument = PDFDocument()
    for i in 0 ..< scan.pageCount {
        let pdfPage = PDFPage(image: scan.imageOfPage(at: i))
            pdfDocument.insert(pdfPage!, at: i)
        }
    return pdfDocument
}
```

I also know how I would extract text out of the `VNDocumentCameraScan`. The thing that I miss is how I incorporate the text information into the `PDFDocument` instance. I need this because I want to scan documents, save them as `.pdf` to the file system and search them afterwards.

I searched a lot but did not find a way to do that.

Does anyone know how I would accomplish this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This blog post covers the topic in detail. I'm linking to Part 3 of a series, since it addresses the part of the process you're stuck on.

https://alexanderweiss.dev/blog/2021-03-29-from-uiimage-to-searchable-pdf-part-3

The main idea is to draw the recognized text underneath the image in your pdf. Basic steps from the article:

> 1. Take the image
> 2. Recognize the text on the image
> 3. Create a PDF page with the dimensions of the image
> 4. Use the recognized text to draw text
> 5. Draw the image above the text on the pdf

VNRecognizedText contains information about the location of recognized text, which allows you to determine where to draw the text. I was able to use the code from this post successfully in my app; although it's not 100% perfect when dealing with handwritten text, it works reasonably well.

Comment: How do you deal with the blocking on the main thread. I couldn't figure out how to run it off the main queue because there is no asynchronous code...